# pointers and references, room "has-a" key

Tags: c++, pointers

I basically want to say, if the current room contains a key, which I have assigned below, then tell the user, the room has a key and I'll figure the rest out.

```
int main()
{

    Room mainHall;
    Room sittingRoom;

    mainHall.setNorthExit(&sittingRoom);
    mainHall.setEastExit(&playRoom);

    mainHall.setDescription("The main hall has 2 exits, one to the north, one to the east");
    mainHall.setName("Main Hall");

    sittingRoom.setEastExit(&kitchen);
    sittingRoom.setSouthExit(&mainHall);

    sittingRoom.setDescription("The sitting room has 2 exits, one to the east and one to the south");
    sittingRoom.setName("Sitting Room");

    string userInput;

    Room* currentRoom;
    currentRoom = &mainHall;

    Keys& key1 = playRoom.getKey();
    key1.setName("Sitting Room");

    Keys& key2 = sittingRoom.getKey();
    key2.setName("Play Room");

    if(////need code here) ///I want it to be something like...if(currentRoom "has a key"
    {
        string takeKey;
        cout << "There is still a key in this room, would you like to take it? " << endl;
        cin >> takeKey;
        if(takeKey == "yes")
        {
               //Havent assigned anything yet
        }
    }
```

This is just the cpp file of my keye class just in case you need it

```
#include"Keys.h"
#include<iostream>

Keys::Keys()
{
    name = "";
}

Keys::Keys(string nameParam)
{
    name = nameParam;
}

void Keys::setName(string nameParam)
{
    name = nameParam;
}

string Keys::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

void Keys::setKey(string keyParam)
{
    key = keyParam;
}

string Keys::getKey() const
{
    return key;
}
```

As well as a getter method in my rooms class

```
Keys& Room::getKey()
{
    return key;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Here's a hint; you're returning a *reference* to a key, which can never be `null`, meaning the room must *always* have a key. You probably want to return a *pointer*, which can be `null` if there is no key for a given room, and then check whether `getKey` returns a null pointer or a pointer to a real `Key`. In fact, many places where you're using `getKey` seem to assume a key will always be returned. You probably want pointers in virtually all the cases you're using references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a 'HasKey()' method on the room class, then use

```
if( sittingRoom.HasKey()) { ... }
```

Use a boolean in the room class to determine if the room has a key.